# Excel calendar for resource planning (using macros)

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use Excel calendar for resource planning where I have prepared the Excel calendar for November. There when you insert the project plan with the activity, start date & end date, I want to write a macro to highlight the range (start date to end date) of cells.

I want to limit the work per person per day to 4 (e.g. for 1/11/2012 I have included 4 rows(`J7:J10`).

Before highlighting the cells, need to check whether those 4 cells are filled, if not highlight the last available. If all 4 has been highlighted display a message.